# python - Need help converting a list comprehension to a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I am learning and practising lambda functions and came across a question that I am not able to solve.
Q - Create a list of fruits with more than 2 vowels.
`fruits = ['mango', 'kiwi', 'strawberry', 'guava', 'pineapple', 'mandarin orange']`

My solution using a list comprehension:

```
result = [fruit for fruit in fruits if len([True for char in fruit if char in "aeiou"]) > 2]
```

This works well but I need to achieve the same output using a lambda function

My attempt using lambda function:

```
result2 = list(filter(lambda x : len(set("aeiou") & set(x)) > 2, fruits))
```

`result2` creates a list of fruits with more than 2 *different* vowels, but I need a list containing fruits that just has more than 2 vowels.

Expected Output - `['guava', 'pineapple', 'mandarin orange']`
Output - `['pineapple', 'mandarin orange']`

Comment: Instead of `len(...) > 2`, you could use `sum(c in "aeiou" for c in fruit) > 2`. Which in turn can easily be turned into a `reduce` call with a lambda function… Or you keep your current `len(...)` logic but use another `filter` with a lambda instead…!?

Comment: I know my current `len(...)` logic is bad and it doesn't work, but that's the reason why I even came here, to find a better solution, I never mentioned that I will only use the `len()` logic only no matter what, did I? I am not able to understand why you are upset.

Comment: You're reading too much into my comment, why would I be upset? Why do you say your `len` logic isn't working; it is, isn't it? It's the `set` approach that is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output using a lambda function by modifying the lambda function to count the total number of vowels in each fruit rather than checking for unique vowels.

```
 result2 = list(filter(lambda x: sum(1 for char in x if char in "aeiou") > 2, fruits))
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```py
filtered_fruits = list(filter(lambda fruit: sum(1 for char in fruit if char in "aeiouAEIOU") >= 3, fruits))
```

This should result

```
['guava', 'pineapple', 'mandarin orange']
```